# Ion-slider last bigger dimension image is still visible

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, slider

I am using ion-slide ionic 1 to display images, it works fine but if I have smaller image as next image on the slide, last bigger image is still visible.

Lets say I have images with 350x150 (grey) then the next one is 140x100 (blue), when its displaying 140x100 image, 350x150 image still displaying with 140x100 at the top of it.[image]

After 2nd image is displayed, grey image of 350x150 image still visible.

[image]

This is my html code :

```
<ion-slides  options="options" slider="data.slider">
        <ion-slide-page ng-repeat="image in items" class="slider-page">
        <img ng-src="http://placehold.it/350x150" ng-if="image.pic_location == 0 && image.imageable_type == 'App\\Item'">
        <img ng-src="http://via.placeholder.com/140/09f/fff.png" ng-if="image.pic_location == 1 && image.imageable_type == 'App\\Item'"> 

        </ion-slide-page>
      </ion-slides>
```

The css involving in ion-slide

```
ion-slides{
  height: 60vh !important;
}
.slider-page{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Items is list of image files from server, containing filename and location information.

I want to completely hide 350x150 image (grey) when it is displaying 140x100 image (blue). How to solve this? and how do normally mobile handle images with different height?

Comment: Can you please post your items data and `class="slider-page"` details?

Comment: I added the css code involing in class="slider-page" and ion-slide